# ASP.NET MVC5 Controller CRUD with ViewModel (2 models)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller, I have a ViewModel containing 2 different models, called Drug and Food.

```
public class FoodDrugViewModel {
        public IEnumerable<SGHealthDesktop.Models.Drug> Drugs { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SGHealthDesktop.Models.Food> Foods { get; set; }

    }
```

In my MainController, this is how I pass in the ViewModel into the Index.

```
 // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult Index() {
            FoodDrugViewModel vm = new FoodDrugViewModel(); //initialize it
            vm.Drugs = db.Drugs.ToList();
            vm.Foods = db.Foods.ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }
```

In my view, I created two tables, and looped the items in each of the model, like this.

```
<table class="table" id="drugTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Drug Name</th>
            <th>Dosage</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Drugs) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DrugName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dosage)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DrugId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.DrugId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.DrugId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

 @foreach (var item in Model.Foods) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Protein)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Carbohydrate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalFat)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.FoodId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.FoodId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.FoodId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

To prevent both tables from showing up at the same time, I used a dropdownlist accompanied with JQuery so user can choose which table to see, and it's working as expected. **However, my issue are as follow**.

When I click on the "Details" ActionLink, or infact any of the 3 ActionLinks (Detail, Edit, Delete), I would like the relevant information to be displayed. For example, if I'm viewing the Drug table and if I click on "Details", the Detail view will display the drug information, and the same for Food.

However, I can't seem to figure out how that can be achieved. My Detail method is as follow, having Drug as the main model still. How can it detect if the user has chose to view the detail of Drug OR Food? As you can see in the code, it immediately finds the Drug details based on the id.

```
// GET: Admin/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id) {
            if (id == null) {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Drug drug = db.Drugs.Find(id);
            if (drug == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(drug);
        }
```

As for Create, there's no problem with it as I can again, allow a dropdownlist so user can choose what type, Drug or Food, they want to create and the form will be shown respectively (assuming in view I'm using the FoodDrugViewModel instead of Drug model). But how can i bind the data in the controller? By default, the Create method is as follow.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DrugId,DrugName,Dosage,Unit,Type")] Drug drug) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                db.Drugs.Add(drug);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(drug);
        }
```

Any help rendered will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: Issue on Create()**

In the Create view, I declared the FoodDrugViewModel as follow

> @model SGHealthDesktop.ViewModels.FoodDrugViewModel

And my Drug form looks like this (the same applies for Food).

```
<div id="drugDiv">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Drug.DrugName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Drug.DrugName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Drug.DrugName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Drug.Dosage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Drug.Dosage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Drug.Dosage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Drug.Unit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Drug.Unit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Drug.Unit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Drug.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Drug.Type,
                     new SelectList(new[]
                    { "Diabetic Medication", "Hypertension", "Kidney Disease", "Insulin", "High Cholesterol"
                    }) as SelectList, new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Drug.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Create() method is as follow

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "DrugName,Dosage,Unit,Type")] FoodDrugViewModel vm) {
            try {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    if (vm.Drug != null) {
                        db.Drugs.Add(vm.Drug);
                    } 
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            } catch (DataException dex) {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(vm.Drug);
        }
```

I placed a breakpoint at the line the method is called, and "Drug" is null. May I know where did I went wrong? :(

Comment: It is possible but it is not such a good idea to use one action for Drug and Food. In terms of maintenance, actions on several things should also be implemented separately.

Comment: Why don't you just have a `FoodController` with methods `Details(int id)`, `Edit(int id)` and the same for `DrugController`? And you will greatly improve performance by loading partials views for you collections by using ajax rather than sending all the data to the view when 50% of it may never be used.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So you're suggesting that I create two individual controllers with its own set of views, and load it as a partial view into my MainController when needed?

Comment: Yes. That is how a typical app is set up - you create controllers for logical groups, usually one per database table.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Understood! Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass one more parameter to your `ActionResult` to differentiate between `Drug` and `Food`. For an example, I would be adding `type` param, with value `drug` and `food` for respective actions.

**Drug**

---

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Drugs) {
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DrugName)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dosage)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Unit)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DrugId, type="drug" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.DrugId, type="drug" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.DrugId, type="drug" })
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

**Food**

---

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Foods) {
<tr>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Protein)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Carbohydrate)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalFat)
  </td>
  <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.FoodId, type="food" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.FoodId, type="food" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.FoodId, type="food" })
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

Your `ActionResult Details` now should be accepting two arguments, `id` and `type`.

```
// GET: Admin/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string type) {
  //You do not want to do anything if you don't have type value too, so the condition
  if (id == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  if(type=="drug"){
      Drug drug = db.Drugs.Find(id);
      if (drug == null) {
         return HttpNotFound();
      }
      return View(drug);
  }
  else
  {
      Food food = db.Foods.Find(id);
      if (food == null) {
         return HttpNotFound();
      }
      return View(food);
  }
}
```

Hope you will be handling your view **efficiently** with different `models` passed.

---

**EDIT**

You might also check it in below way, by adding ternary operation, but am not sure whether it will work or not. You can give a try.

```
// GET: Admin/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string type) {
  //You do not want to do anything if you don't have type value too, so the condition
  if (id == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  var model=type=="drug"?db.Drugs.Find(id):db.Foods.Find('id');
  if (model == null) {
      return HttpNotFound();
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! It worked as expected for the Details. However, I'm currently experiencing some issue with Create. Do you mind helping me take a look at the question? I've updated it.

Comment: Need more details, I can help you better, if you would like to share any social media address.. like gmail..

Comment: You do realize none of this will work unless you have separate Create and Edit methods for Food and Drug

Comment: Hm, let me try creating a partial view instead and loading it into my main view. Someone mentioned that it will be much more efficiency, and also I'm starting to feel that this isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much @GuruprasadRao, I'll try in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two ways to do this.

1. For both Drugs and Foods create 6 different actions like

> Food_Edit, Food_Details, Food_Delete, Drug_Edit, Drug_Details,
>   Drug_Delete

2. Pass Another parameter for the actions indicating the type. In that case you may have to right another routing method.

> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.FoodId, type="Food"
>   })
>
> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.DrugId, type="Drug"
>   })